# Output voltage of MOSFET differential pair with current mirror load

Tags: mosfet, current-mirror, differential-amplifier

I've seen this circuit from https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/advantages-of-the-actively-loaded-mosfet-differential-pair/

[image]

How are the drain voltages equal?? I can't seem to figure it out, it's not even symmetric?

Vd3 = Vsply+ - Vsg = Vsply+ + VGS

I can see that but what about Vd4??It can't be due to symmetry. Q3 forces its drain and gate to be equal with a short, but Q4 doesn't have that.

Comment: Try read this answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/353604/dc-voltage-in-collector-after-active-load/353618#353618  Did this answer help?

Comment: *How are the drain voltages equal??* You're right, usually they aren't equal. **Only** in the **purely theoretical** case where the transistors are **exactly** identical and \$I_{bias}\$ divides exactly half-half between Q1 and Q2 and the output resistances of Q1, Q2 and Q3, Q4 **exactly** match then the drain voltages could be the same. But even in a simulator they will not be the same, for start Q3 has a different Voltage to current relation than Q4 because Q3 has local feedback and Q4 does not. Anyone who claims that the voltages at the drains of Q1, Q2 are equal still has a lot to learn!

Comment: @G36 i still don't know how the drain voltages are equal. But I realized that just as in the  BJT version, there needs to be a wire to sink out the current difference. The current mirror forces both sides to have equal currents, but the differential voltage forces different currents. The current difference must be sinked out by a wire connected to either side of the differential pair.

Comment: In theory, if Vin1 = Vin2 and all transistor are perfectly matched you can get the same voltage at the output.

Comment: @G36  not sure if im stupid but, if the input voltages are equal and all the transistors are matched, then all the transistors have the same currents. But if they are all in saturation, their drain voltages could be anything. if there was no feedback in M3, then I could believe that they are symmetric but m3 does have feedback and m4 doesn't. I'm not sure how to come up with an exact value/equation for Vout.

Comment: You must include the channel length modulation effect into your equations. https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/common-source-stage-with-constant-current-source-load.147146/

Comment: Typically the right hand side (the output) voltage moves up and places the current-mirror into TRIODE mode, or the output voltage moves DOWN and places the diffpair device into TRIODE mode.

Comment: @G36 thanks, when I included channel length modulation effects, I got the desired result vds1= vds2 and vds3=vds4 and thanks for the link :))...But this only happens when all transistors are matched and the inputs to the differential pair are equal, am I right?

Comment: @ElecNoob, Yes, you are right. But you don't need to worry about this too much. Because in real life we always have some have a load resistance and some negative feedback to set the Q-point. And the real benefits from the current mirror is the asymmetric gain increases to gm*RL.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333502/differential-stage-av-value-with-current-sources/333536#333536

Answer (score 1):

Consider this plot of the output characteristics of those two output devices Q2 and Q4

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4xRDw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>